# Media module and StreamWrapper

Tags: media, stream-wrappers

I am using [Media 7.x-1.3](http://drupal.org/project/media) on Drupal 7.21.
I have created simple `StreamWrapper` to use with some other modules and it works great for them. It extends [`DrupalLocalStreamWrapper`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!stream_wrappers.inc/class/DrupalLocalStreamWrapper/7) and overrides [`getDirectoryPath`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!stream_wrappers.inc/function/DrupalLocalStreamWrapper%3a%3agetDirectoryPath/7) and [`getExternalUrl`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!stream_wrappers.inc/function/DrupalStreamWrapperInterface%3a%3agetExternalUrl/7) only.

When I set this `StreamWrapper` as my "Default download method" at admin/config/media/file-system and upload file using Media Browser, I do see this file created at the location it should but Media shows the "404 broken image" icon and when I add it to my node I see the 404 image also.

My `StreamWrapper` saves the files to a local path and serves it through CDN URL.

Do you have any suggestion about how I should work this out?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 for the original image, or is it a generated style that's missing?

Comment: I guess I miss something, what is a "generated style"?
The image is created on the CDN's folder and the URL returned by getExternalURL is correct and points to that file.
I thought maybe something is missing in the thumbnails etc. but I've no idea how to set it up.

Comment: Drupal creates thumbnails (image styles) on-the-fly, you ca

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what is "generated style", did some of your message got lost in the cyber?

Comment: Oops yes it did, but not much. As I mentioned Image styles are the thumbnails Drupal generates, you need to find out if the image that's 404'ing is the original image, or one of these thumbnails generated by Drupal. If it _is_ an image style, you might need to do a bit more coding to integrate your stream wrapper with that system. I think the [Amazon S3 module](http://drupal.org/project/amazon_s3) does something similar but I might be wrong

Comment: That's probably the problem (image styles) but I can't find how to make Drupal create the thumbnails. Can't find in the S3 module.